# Groupby and reshape long to wide formatted dataframe while aggregating elements as arrays

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
    user  order  value
0     1      0     90
1     1     10     80
2     1     20     70
3     2     30     60
4     2     40     50
5     2     50     40
6     3     60     30
7     3     70     20
8     3     80     10
```

And now I wish to reshape it like this, every user get its own row with values. Note that the row is ordered according to the value in the `order`-column in the dataframe.

```
         1    2    3 ...
user
1       90   80   70
2       60   50   40
3       30   20   10
```

or even keep the `order` and any another value in the original dataframe so that each component is an array:

```
          1           2          3 ...
user
1       [0, 90]   [10, 80]   [20, 70]
2       [30, 60]  [40, 50]   [50, 40]
3       [60, 30]  [70, 20]   [80, 10]
```

What is this operation called and is it possible to do in a few lines of code in Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

**first output**:

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `lambda` function where create `numpy array` by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):`:

```
df = df.groupby('user')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns + 1
print (df)
       1   2   3
user            
1     90  80  70
2     60  50  40
3     30  20  10
```

**second output**:

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `lambda` function where create `numpy array` by [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), which are converted to `list` and last to `Series`:

```
#for add 1 tp column names use rename
df = df.groupby('user')
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[['order','value']].values.tolist())
       .rename(index=lambda x: x+1))
print (df)
             1         2         3
user                              
1      [0, 90]  [10, 80]  [20, 70]
2     [30, 60]  [40, 50]  [50, 40]
3     [60, 30]  [70, 20]  [80, 10]

df = df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[['order','value']].values.tolist()))
#add 1 to column names last
df.columns = df.columns + 1
print (df)
             1         2         3
user                              
1      [0, 90]  [10, 80]  [20, 70]
2     [30, 60]  [40, 50]  [50, 40]
3     [60, 30]  [70, 20]  [80, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perform `groupby` on *user* and take it's cumulative count based on the values contained in it. Add one to the obtained result so that the headers get formatted this way (namely - 1,2,3...so on).

Set *user* and the above obtained result as index, `stack` the `DF` to produce a multiindexed series. Groupby on `level=[0,1]` of the multi-index series object and coerce the series to take on array values using `apply`. Finally, `unstack` the frame to obtain the desired result.

```
cc = df.groupby('user').cumcount() + 1
df.set_index(['user', cc]).stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(np.array).unstack()
# alternatively -  a DF level syntax by avoiding the `stack` call
# df.set_index(['user', cc]).groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.values.ravel()).unstack()
```

[image]

---

To get back your first desired result:

```
df.set_index(['user', cc])['value'].unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an answer in the first format:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(data=[
        [1,  0, 90],
        [1, 10, 80],
        [1, 20, 70],
        [2, 30, 60],
        [2, 40, 50],
        [2, 50, 40],
        [3, 60, 30],
        [3, 70, 20],
        [3, 80, 10]
    ], columns=['user', 'order', 'value'])

# do ordering by groups:
groups = X.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('order').value.values)

# recreate the DF. 
X_prime = pd.DataFrame(data=[i.astype(np.int) for i in groups.values], 
                       index=groups.index)
```

This yields:

```
>>> X_prime
       0   1   2
user
1     90  80  70
2     60  50  40
3     30  20  10
```